# Textures selectively not applying in Unity

Tags: unity, textures, blender, fbx

On certain imported objects (fbx) in Unity, upon applying a material, only the base colour of the material is applied, with none of the tiled texture showing. This isn't universal; on a test model only some submeshes didn't show the texture, while some did. I have tried every combination of import/calculate normals/tangents to no avail.

FYI I'm not exactly experienced with the software or gamedev in general; this is to make a small static scene with 3-4 objects max. One model tested was created in 3DSMax, the other in Blender. I've had this happen on every export from Blender, but only some submeshes from the 3DSMax model (internet sourced to test the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's your exact problem but I had similar issues.

It looks like Blender doesn't generate `UV` coords by default. Even if you can render your object with texture in Blender - it doesn't mean you'll have `UVs` in the exported mesh. You need to explicitly add some UV channel - I don't know Blender very well so you need to look for some tutorials for this (But it's very simple, if you know where to click).

In 3D MAX, when you create a basic object and select `Generate mapping coords` you'll get the `UVs` out of the box.

There's also a simple way to verify if that's the case. When your mesh doesn't have an `UV` channel but it's used in the rendering, then your `UV` values will be set up to defaults `(0,0)` - which means that some corner texel will be used as a texture for entire object. Now, if you move or change your texture, so texels on the corners will have different color - your mesh should also change the color during rendering.

Comment: Worked perfectly - I just needed to do a UV Unwrap in Blender before exporting the model. I would upvate, but only have 1 rep atm! Thanks though

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.